# Convergence of continuous functions on compact Hausdorff spaces to a continuous function on product topology

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Let $(X,T_x), (Y,T_y)$ be compact Hausdorff spaces.
Let $f \in C_{\Re}(X \times Y)$ and $\epsilon>0$. Prove that there is $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and functions {$g_j \in C_{\Re}(X):1 \leq j \leq n$} and {$h_j \in C_{Re}(Y): 1 \leq j \leq n$} such that 
$|f(x,y)- \sum _{j=1}^{n}g_j(x)h_j(y)| < \epsilon$ for all $x \in X, y\in Y$.

I have shown that $(X \times Y,T)$ is compact. But I'm not sure if that helps. Not sure how to proceed from here, please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show that the set of all functions on $X \times Y$ of the form

$$\mathcal{A}:= \{f(x,y) = \sum_{i=1}^n f_i(x) g_i(y): n \in \Bbb N, f_1,\ldots, f_n \in C(X), g_1, \ldots g_n \in C(Y)\}$$

forms a subalgebra on $C(X \times Y)$. This is not hard. Show also that it separates points.

Use the [Stone-Weierstraß theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem) to conclude $\mathcal{A}$ is uniformly dense, which is what you had to show.